# How can I load site in new page automatically?

Tags: html

I build a HTML page that when enter to page, it load a other site in 'For' loop.
My problem that when I load the page I move to the second site and my for loop break. so I want to build a code that open the second site in new page **without move to second site (the second site will open in other page and my page continue to work).**

here my code:

```html
var i;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

<head>
       <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0 ; url=http://www.azim.co.il/be-a-part/"/>
    </head>

 
}
```

I will be happy with someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to open new page in new tab,

I think this is helpful to you

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; URL=javascript:window.open('http://www.azim.co.il/be-a-part/');">
```